# How to strip outgoing mail headers in postfix?

Tags: postfix, email

I have a mail server running on my box. I have webmail access, as well as ability to send mail thru a client. When I send mail thru a web interface (roundcube) it attaches its own headers, so the sender is kept anonymous.

When sending mail thru Outlook, or Thunderbird, it attaches its own header, which lists the IP address, computer name, etc. Is there a way to ahve postfix strip these outgoing headers, and replace them with the standard "web mail" header that I get with roundcube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some useful links:

http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html

http://www.maniacmartin.com/2008/12/23/stripping-headers-postfix/

http://www.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/securityfocus/focus-linux/2006-01/msg00015.html